# Web browser doesn't retrieve all data

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I am new to `WebBrowser` library.

When fetching data from `https://www.binance.com/indexSpa.html` website, I used the following code. But it does not return all the data. What should I do?

```
  WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
  wb.DocumentCompleted += Wb_DocumentCompleted;
  wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
  wb.Navigate(@"https://www.binance.com/indexSpa.html#");

  private void Wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
  {
      var wb = (WebBrowser)sender;
      Console.WriteLine(wb.DocumentText);
  }
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: Do you require the `WebBrowser` control, or is your goal to retrieve the content of the website someway?

Comment: What kind of "data" is not being retrieved?